# How do I show controls on top of a gradient background with pure WINAPI?

Tags: c++, c, winapi

In my program I am trying to create a child window (via `CreateWindow("STATIC", ...)`) to contain some other controls such as edit boxes and buttons.  However, I want the background for this static control to be a gradient.

My goal is to have something that looks like this as a child window:

[image]

My efforts so far have yielded the window being created with controls visible but as soon as it is redrawn with `WM_ERASEBKGND`, the controls are hidden behind the drawn gradient.

I can find plenty of examples on drawing a gradient (or other such graphic backgrounds) and also, independently, creating a window with controls. But I have yet to find any resource of having both at the same time.

Here is my example code:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

#pragma comment( lib, "Msimg32" )   // load that dll for GradientFill

// Global macros
inline COLOR16 ToColor16(BYTE byte) { return byte << 8; }
inline COLOR16 RVal16(COLORREF color) { return ToColor16(GetRValue(color)); }
inline COLOR16 GVal16(COLORREF color) { return ToColor16(GetGValue(color)); }
inline COLOR16 BVal16(COLORREF color) { return ToColor16(GetBValue(color)); }

// Global variables
HINSTANCE hInst;

// Forward declarations
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

// Entry point
int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    // Register the window class.
    const TCHAR CLASS_NAME[] = "mcvewinapi";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.
    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        "MCVE WINAPI",                  // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        300,                    //horizontal position
        50,                     //vertical position
        700,                    //width
        500,                    //height

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    hInst = hInstance;

    if (hwnd == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

// vill geven area with vertical gradient
void VerticalGradient(HDC hDC, const RECT &RectToFill, COLORREF rgbTop, COLORREF rgbBottom) {
    GRADIENT_RECT gradRect;
    TRIVERTEX TriVert[2];

    // references for the verticies
    gradRect.UpperLeft = 0;     // point to TriVert[0]
    gradRect.LowerRight = 1;    // point to TriVert[1]

    //setup top of gradient attributes
    TriVert[0].x = RectToFill.left - 1;
    TriVert[0].y = RectToFill.top - 1;
    TriVert[0].Red = RVal16(rgbTop);
    TriVert[0].Green = GVal16(rgbTop);
    TriVert[0].Blue = BVal16(rgbTop);
    TriVert[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

    //setup bottom of gradient attributes
    TriVert[1].x = RectToFill.right;
    TriVert[1].y = RectToFill.bottom;
    TriVert[1].Red = RVal16(rgbBottom);
    TriVert[1].Green = GVal16(rgbBottom);
    TriVert[1].Blue = BVal16(rgbBottom);
    TriVert[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

    // draw the shaded rectangle
    GradientFill(hDC, TriVert, 2, &gradRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
}

// discover area to fill with gradient
void vFill(HWND ctrlhwnd) {
    HDC gBoxDC;
    HWND gBoxH;
    RECT gBoxR;
    POINT xWhere;

    // get rectangle from control
    gBoxH = ctrlhwnd;
    GetWindowRect(gBoxH, &gBoxR);

    // get DC for control
    gBoxDC = GetDC(gBoxH);

    // load up RECT from POINT
    xWhere = { gBoxR.left, gBoxR.top };
    ScreenToClient(gBoxH, &xWhere);
    gBoxR.left = xWhere.x + 2;
    gBoxR.top = xWhere.y + 2;

    // load up RECT from POINT
    xWhere = { gBoxR.right, gBoxR.bottom };
    ScreenToClient(gBoxH, &xWhere);
    gBoxR.right = xWhere.x - 1;
    gBoxR.bottom = xWhere.y - 1;

    //paint area
    VerticalGradient(gBoxDC, gBoxR, RGB(250, 191, 145), RGB(191, 191, 191));

    ReleaseDC(gBoxH, gBoxDC);
}

// Processes messages for the main window.
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (message) {
        case WM_CREATE:
            struct wAnchor {
                int udPos;
                int lrPos;
                int width;
                int height;
            };
            wAnchor Section1[4], TextLine;
            unsigned int LineHeight, k;
            HWND FillBox;

            LineHeight = 24;

            Section1[1].lrPos = 5;
            Section1[1].udPos = 20;
            Section1[1].width = 325;
            Section1[1].height = 360;

            TextLine.lrPos = Section1[1].lrPos + 5;
            TextLine.udPos = Section1[1].udPos + 5;
            TextLine.width = 0;
            TextLine.height = LineHeight;

            k = 1;

            FillBox = CreateWindow("STATIC",
                "",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                Section1[1].lrPos,
                Section1[1].udPos,
                Section1[1].width,
                Section1[1].height,
                hWnd,                   // child of parent
                (HMENU)8200,
                hInst,
                NULL);

            CreateWindow("STATIC",
                "Section title",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | SS_CENTER | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                TextLine.lrPos,
                TextLine.udPos + (TextLine.height * k++),
                TextLine.width + 315,
                TextLine.height,
                FillBox,                // child of FillBox
                (HMENU)8201,
                hInst,
                NULL);

            CreateWindow("STATIC",
                "Entry:",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                TextLine.lrPos,
                TextLine.udPos + (TextLine.height * k),
                TextLine.width + 75,
                TextLine.height,
                FillBox,                // child of FillBox
                (HMENU)8202,
                hInst,
                NULL);

            CreateWindow("EDIT", // edit bos
                "109",
                WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_TABSTOP | ES_MULTILINE,
                TextLine.lrPos + 75,
                TextLine.udPos + (TextLine.height * k),
                TextLine.width + 35,
                TextLine.height,
                FillBox,                // child of FillBox
                (HMENU)8203,
                hInst,
                NULL);

            CreateWindow(
                "BUTTON",       // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
                "test",         // Button text 
                WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
                50,             // x position 
                150,            // y position 
                50,             // Button width
                30,             // Button height
                FillBox,        // child of FillBox
                (HMENU)8204,    // No menu
                hInst,
                NULL);          // Pointer not needed
            UpdateWindow(FillBox);
            break;
        case WM_PAINT: {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
            break;
        case  WM_ERASEBKGND:
            vFill(GetDlgItem(hWnd, 8200)); //fill background with gradient
            return 1L;
            break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Initially, no gradient is drawn until I resize the window, then the gradient covers the controls. Of course, I would like the gradient to be redrawn as needed, but the controls to remain visible.

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the [`WS_CLIPCHILDREN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) style to the parent window:

```
FillBox = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"),
    TEXT(""),
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    Section1[1].lrPos,
    Section1[1].udPos,
    Section1[1].width,
    Section1[1].height,
    hWnd,                   // child of parent
    (HMENU)8200,
    hInst,
    NULL);
```

This will not include its child windows when drawing the parent window, which works for me:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to create a window to act as a container for some controls, the obvious choice is usually to create a dialog. It already (automatically) handles most of what you're doing right now, and a few things you might want to (like using the tab to move between controls) but haven't yet.

So, for example, starting from a generic Windows app, I changed the default `About` box to host roughly the controls you wanted, then popped it up as a modeless dialog when the application initialized.

```cpp
// frame.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "framework.h"
#include "frame.h"

#pragma comment( lib, "Msimg32" )   // load that dll for GradientFill


#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_FRAME, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_FRAME));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_FRAME));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_FRAME);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND dialog;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        dialog = CreateDialog(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
        ShowWindow(dialog, SW_SHOW);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

inline COLOR16 ToColor16(BYTE byte) { return byte << 8; }
inline COLOR16 RVal16(COLORREF color) { return ToColor16(GetRValue(color)); }
inline COLOR16 GVal16(COLORREF color) { return ToColor16(GetGValue(color)); }
inline COLOR16 BVal16(COLORREF color) { return ToColor16(GetBValue(color)); }

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_ERASEBKGND: {
        COLORREF rgbTop(RGB(250, 191, 145));
        COLORREF rgbBottom(RGB(191, 191, 191));

        RECT RectToFill;
        GetClientRect(hDlg, &RectToFill);

        GRADIENT_RECT gradRect;
        TRIVERTEX TriVert[2];

        // references for the verticies
        gradRect.UpperLeft = 0;     // point to TriVert[0]
        gradRect.LowerRight = 1;    // point to TriVert[1]

        //setup top of gradient attributes
        TriVert[0].x = RectToFill.left - 1;
        TriVert[0].y = RectToFill.top - 1;
        TriVert[0].Red = RVal16(rgbTop);
        TriVert[0].Green = GVal16(rgbTop);
        TriVert[0].Blue = BVal16(rgbTop);
        TriVert[0].Alpha = 0x0000;

        //setup bottom of gradient attributes
        TriVert[1].x = RectToFill.right;
        TriVert[1].y = RectToFill.bottom;
        TriVert[1].Red = RVal16(rgbBottom);
        TriVert[1].Green = GVal16(rgbBottom);
        TriVert[1].Blue = BVal16(rgbBottom);
        TriVert[1].Alpha = 0x0000;

        HDC dc = GetDC(hDlg);
        GradientFill(dc, TriVert, 2, &gradRect, 1, GRADIENT_FILL_RECT_V);
        ReleaseDC(hDlg, dc);
        return TRUE;
    }

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

I didn't really complete the transformation from it being a modal dialog to modeless (e.g., a modeless dialog usually won't have an OK button, or code to handle its being pressed, but it's still enough to get the idea of how it can look:

[image]

Comment: A dialog would be easier, however my example was just from a much bigger project.  My need is actually to have containers like this on just one page of a tab control.  But thanks for the help.